# Passwordless authentication to Samba server

Tags: authentication, samba

I have a Samba server in an openwrt router and shares configured usng smbpasswd with no guest access.

I have two Windows 10 pro computers both in the same workgroup as configured in Samba.

Computer 1 can immediately access the Samba shares with an absolutely brand new never-used account (preconfigured in Samba) and without entering any authentication detail to access the share.

Computer 2 however, asks for username and password for the same user, which I don't want to be required to happen.

Both computers don't list any shares when running "net use".

There thus seems to be something different in the configuration on computer 1 from computer 2.

Does anyone know what this difference might be?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem related to Wifi settings on Windows - whether Windows considered the network to be a public or private network.

Switching the wifi network to private network instead of public network made it work like the other computer.